Is there Uniswap V2/V3 function to get initial token supply amount in pool?
I need to get initial token supply when liquidity pool was created by querying Ethereum node (RPC) or Uniswap contract and not Mint() function, is it possible to do (python)?
To get reserves on any block I can by contract.functions.getReserves().call(block_identifier=N), but the problem if there were trades in that block, I will receive reserves by that end of block, not initial.
Why not Mint() function: because finding it in blockchain will take time and also decoding topics functions also take time, but I need to get it fast.

Because the data is public, everything is possible. Is there a function? No.
You can create a custom per-transaction indexer that walks through all transactions within a block and maintains a state for the pools. TheGraph has some technology to do this. However it is likely to be many days/weeks worth of work.
